# "Array check interrupted" error in a .COM-file with 8086 assembly. Trying to find the maximum number in an array

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

```
[org 0x0100]
jmp start
max1:   
max:    mov si, 0                       ;for loop counter
        mov ax, [arr + si]              ;storing the first element of the array
        mov bx, 2   
        mov cx, 0                       
        mov dx, [arr + si + bx]         ;storing the second element
        cmp dx, ax                      ;comparing if dx is greater than ax
        jg store1                       ;if yes, jmp to store1

        add si, 2                       ;if not, inc the si
        cmp si, 18                      ;comparing for the loop counter
        je exit1                        ;if si=18, jmp to exit1

        jmp max

store1: mov ax, dx                      ;if condition on line 13 is true, jmp here and move dx into ax
        mov word[maxnum], ax            ;mov the new value of ax into maxnum
        add si, 2                       ;inc si
        jmp max                         ;go back to start of the loop

exit1:  pop dx
        pop cx
        pop bx
        pop ax
        pop si
        ret

start:  mov si, 0
        mov ax, 0
        mov bx, 0
        mov cx, 0
        mov dx, 0

        push si
        push ax
        push bx
        push cx
        push dx     
        call max1

mov ax, 0x4c00
int 0x21

arr: dw 6,4,1,7,9,10,11,13,3,2
maxnum: dw 0
```

I'm new to assembly language.

All I'm getting is

> Array check interrupted

The program keeps on crashing.
What does this mean? How can fix that?
And what condition should I be using if there's a negative number in the array?

This works perfectly fine without the sub-routine.

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Also, learn to use a debugger to step through your program and see where it goes wrong yourself. That said, you can't pop the registers at `exit1` because the return address is still in the way. Use `ret 10` instead. `jg` is signed, so it will work for negative numbers. PS: not sure why you even push all those registers, if you just want to preserve them (not that you need to), move the pops to after the `call max1`.

Comment: @Jester Although `ret 10` will balance the stack, it won't do any good for the actual register contents.

Comment: @SepRoland of course. That's why I also wrote the `if you just want to preserve them (not that you need to), move the pops to after the call max1`. It wasn't clear what OP wanted, the `ret 10` works if he intended them as arguments to a stdcall function.

Answer (score 1):

Your program **crashes** because it gets into an infinite loop caused by a misplaced `max:` label.
You need to write the `max:` label **below** the initialization of `SI`. Now you repeat it over and over again:

```
max1:   ...
        mov si, 0               ;for loop counter
max:    mov ax, [arr + si]
```

All those `push`'s and `pop`'s can be omitted. There's no point in preserving anything since you immediately exit to DOS.
If you insist on preserving then move these `push`'s to the beginning of the subroutine:

```
max1:    push    si
         push    ax 
         push    bx
         push    cx
         push    dx
         mov     si, 0
         ...
```

Even if you stored a new maximum, you must check for the end condition:

```
store1: mov [maxnum], dx        ;mov the new value of dx into maxnum
        add si, 2
        cmp si, 18
        jne max                 ;go back to start of the loop
exit1:  pop dx
        ...
```

---

You can tidy up a bit. You don't use the `CX` register and don't need the `BX` register. Replace

```
mov bx, 2   
mov cx, 0                       
mov dx, [arr + si + bx]         ;storing the second element
```

by

```
mov dx, [arr + si + 2]    ;storing the second element
```

---

> And what condition should I be using if there's a negative number in the array?

Your program already deals with the possibility of negative numbers since you wrote `jg store1`. (`jg` is for signed numbers, `ja` is for unsigned numbers)